# Microsoft Edge - Automatic logon not working with IKEv2 VPN

Tags: authentication, microsoft-edge

We use automatic login for our intranet pages.

Auto login works fine except when I connect to IKEv2 VPN. I haven't figured out why, and I'm running out of options.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Does this problem also occur in other browsers, such as Chrome? Make sure you have set this in `Internet Options`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZxag.png

Comment: Yes it happens in every Browser.

Internet Options is set. With the Watchguard SSLVPN Client the autologon works but not with the build in VPN IKEv2.

Comment: In this case, it looks like it's not a browser-specific issue and has to do with certain settings in the VPN tool you mentioned. Maybe it has something to do with network settings?